# Copying images from Excel to Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have code that works that copies information from Word and pastes it into Excel. The code is:

```
Sub ExceltoLabel_ActiveX()
    Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook

    'only allow the user to select one file
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
    'make the file dialog visible to the user
    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
    'determine what choice the user made

    If intChoice <> 0 Then
        'get the file path selected by the user
        strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPath)

    ThisDocument.Label1.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    ThisDocument.Label3.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
    ThisDocument.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3"))
    ThisDocument.Image2.Picture = LoadPicture(exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4"))
    ThisDocument.Image21.Picture = LoadPicture(exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A6"))

    exWb.Close

    Set exWb = Nothing

End Sub
```

But I need to do it the other way round: copy from an Excel and paste it in a Word, I have the following code that at the moment copies text, but it's not working with images:

```
Sub ExceltoLabel_ActiveX()
    Dim objWord As New Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document

    'only allow the user to select one file
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
    'make the file dialog visible to the user
    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

    'determine what choice the user made
    If intChoice <> 0 Then
        'get the file path selected by the user
        strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(strPath)

    doc.Label1.Caption = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
    'LoadPicture(ActiveSheet.Range("A3")) = doc.Image1.Picture

    doc.Close

End Sub
```

I need to copy an image from the Excel and paste it in the word, but at the moment, I can't...

Comment: First, don't do this: ` Dim objWord As New Word.Application` Dim as Word.Application then Set objWord = New Word.Application. Always. This isn't VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
doc.Label1.Caption = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
```

won't work, because ActiveSheet.Range("A2") refers to value in A2, not to shape. You may pick shapes in the loop and paste them to the Word document, for instance:

```
Dim sh As Shape
Dim par As Paragraph
For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    sh.Copy
    Set par = doc.Paragraphs.Add(Range:=doc.Paragraphs(doc.Paragraphs.Count).Range)
    par.Range.Paste
Next sh
```

This may however work erratic, depending on how you have inserted pics into excel. Anyway, I think you could modify my code to suit your needs.

Comment: We are using Active X contrlols (picture) and the error that appears is: method 'picture' of object 'iimage' failed